# Cybersource not accepting the requestor id from apple

Tags: node.js, swift, applepay, cybersource

I am integrating Apple Pay with my app. I got the payment token from apple. Cybersource does not accept the Apple Pay transaction id. I am sending the transaction id to the requestor id field. but an error shows that the requestor id should not be more than 11 digits. What's the better way to fix this?